# buildout cant instal django cms 2.2

Tags: python, django, makefile, django-cms, buildout

I try to run sudo bin/buildout and I get the following error

Traceback:

```
Getting distribution for 'django-cms==2.2'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2147, in main

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2133, in with_ei_usage

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2150, in <lambda>

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 370, in run

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 594, in easy_install

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 643, in install_item

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 833, in install_eggs

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1055, in build_and_install

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1040, in run_setup

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 63, in run_setup
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 109, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 62, in runner
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 38, in _execfile
  File "/tmp/easy_install-Q5iQTO/django-cms-2.2/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-Q5iQTO/django-cms-2.2/cms/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
An error occurred when trying to install django-cms 2.2. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing django.
  Getting distribution for 'django-cms==2.2'.
Error: Couldn't install: django-cms 2.2
```

Buildout.cfg:

```
[versions]
django = 1.3
django-registration = 0.8-alpha-1
django-filebrowser = 3.0-no-grappelli-2
django-cms = 2.2
```

I tried googling and it says that this error may occur when django version is not 1.3, however here it is specified that django must be 1.3

Any ideas how can I solve this ? If you need anything else please let me know.

Comment: This is a bug in the Django-CMS package; it is importing itself *while installing*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how can I solve this ?

Comment: Why do you want to install such an old version of django-cms. You are using django 1.6, and most likely the older version would not work anyways.. I would go for the latest stable release - 3.0.3

Comment: It's a bug with version 2.x; I guess. Until [this commit](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/commit/accaf20c35b0df2d50bb6e90de9d4e6d827328a7) you'll have these problems; that became part of the 3.x series.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into an issue where you have a globally importable `django.conf.settings` module available. The `django-cms` package *until version 3.0* counts on that module *not* being importable during installation.

What happens is that during setup, the setup script imports the `cms` package to read the version number, but that same package *also* tries to patch your Django settings. This is guarded with a `ImportError` exception handler only; e.g. if the import of `django.conf.settings` fails then don't patch the settings.

When you have a global Django installation, the import *doesn't fail*, however, but throws a different exception instead, as you *have no Django configuration* when you are installing django-cms.

Either upgrade to django-cms 3.x or remove your global Django installation.